# LoadableComponent in Selenium: isLoaded method is not used when class object comes from another class

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

First time poster..

I just started using LoadableComponent model from Selenium and it sounds like a great idea. However, I don't quite understand how isLoaded method is being called. Let me give you my example:

I have two model classes MainPage and SignIn, SignIn page is being loaded when clicking "Sign In" link in MainPage. Here is the code for MainPage:

```
public class MainPage extends LoadableComponent<MainPage>
{
private final WebDriver driver;
@FindBy(linkText = "Sign In")
WebElement              signIn;

public MainPage(WebDriver driver)
{
    this.driver = driver;
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);

}

@Override
public void isLoaded() throws Error
{
    System.out.println("isLoaded main page being called");
    assertEquals(
            driver.getTitle(),
            "Main page title",
            "Invalid title for Home page");

}

@Override
public void load()
{
    driver.get(Constants.URL_HOME);

}

public SignInPage signIn()
{
    signIn.click();
    return new SignInPage(driver);
}
```

Here's the code for SignInPage:

```
public class SignInPage extends LoadableComponent<SignInPage>
{
private final WebDriver driver;
@FindBy(xpath = "//a[@class='action-link registration']")
WebElement              register;

public SignInPage(WebDriver driver)
{
    this.driver = driver;
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);

}

@Override
public void isLoaded() throws Error
{
    System.out.println("Calling isLoaded()...");
    String url = driver.getCurrentUrl();
    assertTrue(url.endsWith("account/signIn"));
    WebElement h1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@data-label='SIGN_IN']"));
    assertTrue(h1.getText().equals("THIS SHOULD REALLY FAIL"));
}

@Override
public void load()
{
    driver.get(Constants.URL_SIGNIN);

}

public UserRegistrationPage register()
{
    register.click();
    return new UserRegistrationPage(driver);
}

public String getTitle()
{
    return driver.getTitle();
}
}
```

**Now** the test is quite basic, I am loading the MainPage and clicking on SignIn link. I would expect to see that isLoaded() method is called once for MainPage and once for SignIn page. However, isLoaded() is being called twice for MainPage and never for SignIn page. I fail to understand why...
Here's the test:

```
@Test
public void newRegistration()
{
    MainPage mainpage = new MainPage(driver).get();
    SignInPage signInPage = mainpage.signIn();
    UserRegistrationPage userRegPage = signInPage.register();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it. The code in test should be:

```
 UserRegistrationPage userRegPage = signInPage.register();
 userRegPage.get();
```

A bit odd to me, but...

Comment: The [JavaDoc](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/LoadableComponent.html) mentions this: _"The expected usage is: `new HypotheticalComponent().get();`"_